# SharePoint 2016: Showing error "Your connection to this site is not fully secure"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, 2016, ssl, browser-compatibility

I am getting this error on google chrome and firefox web browser but it is not coming up in IE browser:

> Your connection to this site is not fully secure.

I have checked SSL certificates and it is all fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Always check the developer console in the browser when you receive errors.  The reason the page is not secure will be in there.  It will likely be some asset on the site loaded using http.

Comment: it comes up with below 2 error on console.

1ST error 

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://microsoft.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

2nd error
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://go2.microsoft.com/ .... Silverlight.createObject @

Comment: it seems to me that wherever I have a video on my page I get this error.
when I go to normal page with NO video I don't get any error.

Comment: @Nbibi That means the video is embedded using http rather than https.  Anything referenced or embedded on the page has to use https if the page is using https to avoid this error.  It's the 2nd error you mention above.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you have mixed-up content like http and https secured and non secured content respectively and this does come from SharePoint, it comes from browser security policy. We can verify this non secured content from the developer debug console tool.

Follow the below steps for to verify the non secured content :

- Right-click on the page where you are getting this error.
- Select inspect element
- Once you have done look for any "Mixed Content" warnings.

For details description please read the below thread :

[SSL And Security](https://in.godaddy.com/community/SSL-And-Security/quot-Your-connection-is-not-fully-secure-quot-Google-Chrome/td-p/50372)

And also verify below steps :

- Open the website on Google Chrome
- Press F12
- Open the network tab
- Press f5 to reload everthing

There it has all the information you should need. Hover over a request to check whether it uses http or https

Similar question is discussed here :

[Chrome - You connection to this site is not fully secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563293/chrome-you-connection-to-this-site-is-not-fully-secure)